# How can i do two groupings in single query in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

I have a table with three columns `Stud_Name`, `Operated_By`, `Status`

```
Stud_Name   Operated_By      Status
 Sri             1               Aprove
 Manoj           1               Aprove
 Ranjan          1               Rejected
 Arif            3               Rejected
```

I want the following result:

```
Operated_By    Aprove   Rejected
   1            2          1
   3            0          1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c006/2/0):

```
SELECT Operated_By,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Aprove' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Aprove,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Rejected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Rejected
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Operated_By
```